# I am creating edit page using PHP Laravel 5.8. I have created routes and url, but error 404 not found shows up

Tags: php, laravel, routes, edit, laravel-5.8

I am learning the Laravel by building a job portal app. And I am coding for the company side to edit their post. 
Now I could go to url, ex) `http://localhost:8000/jobs/23/edit`. But on the screen shows me `404|not found` error message

[This is an screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF7rk.png)

for edit page, I created views/jobs/edit.blade.php.

Of course, data is clearly inserted in my job table.

I tried to clear all the cache and, executed following commands.

```
1. composer dump-autoload

2. php artisan clear-compiled

3. php artisan optimize

4. php artisan config:cache
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/jobs/{id}/edit', 'JobController@edit')->name('job.edit');
```

**JobController.php**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $jobs = Job::findOrFail($id);
    return view('jobs.myjob',compact('jobs'));
}
```

**my-job.blade.php**
I have an edit button and following code is a link it has.

```
{{route('job.edit',[$job->id])}}
```

My environment is Windows, XAMPP and local MySQL server.

Comment: Do you have a record with id=23 in your jobs table?

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of `http://localhost:8000/jobs/23/edit` page

Comment: are you reaching at `edit()` function..? Please check `dd($id)` in edit method

Comment: Hi, Yes job table has a record with id=23. And I added a screen shot. So please check it out.

Comment: just for testing add new route `Route::get('/test-jobs/{id}/edit', 'JobController@edit')->name('test-job.edit');` and try.

Comment: Dear skdroid. Hello ! I tried new route, and created a new blade.php under views/test-jobs/. Then finally I could make it ! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way :

```
<a href="{{route('job.edit',['id'=>$job->id])}}">Edit Job {{$job->id}}</a>
```

you can clear route cache by :

```
php artisan route:clear
```

update : run following command to clear cache

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Hi,

I'm pretty sure that this is the good answer.
And, I suggest you to try implicit model binding wich is really awesome and makes the code simpler: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: So sorry but it doesn't work. The result was totally same.

Answer (score 0):

I finally could solve this problem.

1. I changed to a new route.

   Route::get('/test-jobs/{id}/edit', 'JobController@edit')->name('test-job.edit');
2. I created new blade.php like this, views/test-jobs/edit.blade.php
3. I also changed JobController.php

   public function edit($id){
           $jobs = Job::findOrFail($id);
           return view('test-jobs.edit',compact('jobs'));
       }

And finally, my-job.blade.php which has an edit button like this.

```
 <a href="{{route('test-jobs.edit',[$job->id])}}"><button class="btn btn-dark">Edit</button></a>
```

But still, I don't know why it worked.

And also, I think I need another solution. Because in this way, I needed to create another new folder in views.

So if someone knows another solution, please let me know. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the line `return view('jobs.myjob',compact('jobs'));` in your `JobController.php`, it returns the following view: `resources/views/jobs/myjob.blade.php` (which probably doesn't exist).

try changing the line `return view('jobs.myjob',compact('jobs'));` to `return view('jobs.edit',compact('jobs'));`, after the change it refers to `resources/views/jobs/edit.blade.php` and that should solve your problem.